# Poll and checkout at different levels in SVN repository

Tags: jenkins

We have a Visual Studio solution containing about a dozen class library projects. They're our team's main internal framework. In Jenkins we would like to automate the building of these projects as soon as a check-in is made, and also publish a new version to our local NuGet repo.

The problem: We would like to trigger the build by polling SVN at the class library level, e.g. **..trunk/OurSolution/OurCoreProject**. Changes in one project should not trigger a build on all the other projects. But the checkout needs to be done one level higher, e.g. at **..trunk/OurSolution**, and I cannot figure out how this can be done.

We've tried and contemplated a few solutions already:

- Checking out at project level and then send the .csproj file to
  MsBuild.exe instead of the .sln file. This fails because the project
  expects a sibling folder named .nuget.
- Looking into the Multiple SCMs
  plugin, but it seems to mainly add the ability to use different SCM
  providers in the same project(?) I would like to avoid adding this
  plugin until I know it solves this.
- Splitting all the projects up into separate solutions. Doesn't feel very optimal...

Is there a way to solve this in Jenkins? Have a missed any viable solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you have missed something... the <kbd>**Advanced...**</kbd> button on the Subversion checkout configuration.

- Do your SVN checkout on `..trunk/OurSolution`
- Click <kbd>Advanced...</kbd>
- Under **Included Regions**, type `..trunk/OurSolution/OurCoreProject/*`

For more info, click the <kbd>**?**</kbd> icon next to relevant text area on the UI

> If set, and Jenkins is set to poll for changes, Jenkins will ignore any files and/or folders that are ***not*** in this list when determining if a build needs to be triggered.

Comment: OK, this sounds just like what I was looking for. This problem is related to work, so I'll try it out first thing Monday morning. Thx!